# Consumo de certificados P.12 de Google Analytics con X509Certificate2

Tags: vb.net, google-analytics

Hola estoy consumiendo la API de Google Analytics (GA) desde un proyecto en visual basic, todo muy bien a nivel local, leo el certificado armo la consulta y magia; pero en el IIS la cosa no hay forma de que funcione, siempre me dice que no encuentra el archivo, yo asumo que es el archivo p.12 del certificado pero tampoco lo puedo saber con claridad, pero es el único archivo que leo

```
Dim certificado As String = "C:\MyCertificado.p12"
Dim cuentaDeServicio As String = "micuenta@micuenta"
Dim keyPassword As String = "millavesecretaquenoessecreta"
Dim websiteCode As String = "0000000"

Dim certificate As X509Certificate2
certificate = New X509Certificate2(certificado, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
```

Como les dije a nivel local a modo debug todo bien, voy a GA y traigo los datos, pero a nivel de servidor en IIS no funciona como debería. Yo en el proyecto tengo montada la ruta en una llave del config, pero no importa donde ponga el certificado y la dirección que le configure siempre me da la misma excepción

```
@"Error en la consulta: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   en -.ConsultarVisitasGoogleAnalytics(Int32 P_Anio, Int32 P_Pagina) en -\cls_Historico.vb:línea 185"
```

Ahora bien, pensé que podían ser permisos, pero incluso use una clase impersonator para que cuando se ejecuta la linea de código donde se valida el certificado lo haga con mi propio usuario, pero igual nada parece funcionar.

Pd: El certificado si esta en la dirección correcta

Answer (score 0):

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificado, keyPassword,
                  X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet 
                  | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Comment: Es una respuesta? no se entiende...